# How do I dismiss a Rails flash message after some duration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to set the number of seconds a [flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) notice is shown to the user, before it is automatically dismissed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use some simple JavaScript on your page (using jQuery in this example):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#flash').slideUp();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Assuming the id of the HTML element holding your flash message is `#flash`, this will slide it up and hide it after 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds).

Comment: IIRC rails flashes have a default `class = notice`

Comment: `Rails new` doesn't put the flash in `layouts/application.html.erb` by default, and the code sample [in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) doesn't use a class at all. Do you mean the scaffold templates?

Comment: That's what I was thinking of.

Comment: These answers made me realise that the flashes default is to remain visible indefinitely, rather than be dismissed after a certain period of time. I assumed it was a rails-configurable time, when in fact it was explicitly designed to go away in the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

Just combining what @LouisSimoneau and @rlecaro2 already mentioned – I currently use:

```
function clearNotice(){
  $(".notice").animate({opacity:'0'}, 1500);
}
```

Note that if your using rails 4 with turbolinks, you'll need to call it from a `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

var ready = function() {    
   setTimeout(clearNotice, 1000);  //Flash fade
};
```