# Rails increase duration of flash[:error] message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the easiest/best way to increase the display duration of an individual flash[:error] message in a Rails 4 application?

the code that does the message is in a controller and the pertinent section looks like this:

```
  else
    flash[:notice] = t(:no_new_media, source: @channel.external_source.capitalize)
    flash[:error] = @error['message'] if @error.present?
    redirect_to admin_channel_path(@channel)
  end
```

I'd like to increase the display duration of the error message but I don't care either way about the notice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467157/how-do-i-dismiss-a-rails-flash-message-after-some-duration

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new custom flash message type. More detail [here](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/register-your-own-flash-types-rails-4-countdown-to-2013).

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
    ...
  add_flash_types :error, :another_custom_type
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    redirect_to home_path,
      another_custom_type: "An error message for the user"
  end
end
```

Now in your view check `flash[:another_custom_type].present?` and set duration of message on the basis of that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try like this:
[reference](https://reinteractive.com/posts/13-ui-tips-for-flash-messages-in-rails)

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#test').slideUp();
  }, 5000);
});
```

I consider the id of the HTML element that has a flash message is #test, this will hide it after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

**OR**

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee

$ ->
  flashCallback = ->
    $(".flash-message").fadeOut()
  $(".flash-message").bind 'click', (ev) =>
    $(".flash-message").fadeOut()
  setTimeout flashCallback, 3000
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Craig if you satisfy with my answer then make it correct and vote up